# Remove posts with specific class name from related posts - WP

Tags: php, wordpress

Some of my posts have a class name ‘disabled’ and I have to remove them from related posts because they have a style display: none so it inserts it but doesn’t display it.

How can I filter posts with a class name disabled and add them to 'posts__not_in' to avoid them?

```
<?php
$related = get_posts( array( 
    'numberposts' => 4, 
    'post__not_in' => array($post->ID) 
) );
     
if( $related ) foreach( $related as $post ) {
setup_postdata($post); ?>
     
       <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="card <?php if( get_field('public') == 'no') echo 'disabled' ?>">
          <p><?php the_title();?></p>
       </a>
    
<?php } wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation would be to create a category and assign it to the posts. Then use a tax_query to filter out these posts from your get_posts(). Example below is Psuedo code:

```
$related = get_posts([ 
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'numberposts' => 4, 
    'post__not_in' => [$post->ID],
    'tax_query' => [
        [
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'DISABLED_CATEGORY_SLUG',
            'operator'  => 'NOT IN'
        ],
    ],
]);
```